# Best way to setup USB mic as system default on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-2, alsa

I am trying to setup Jasper on my RPi 2 B by following these instructions http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/#configure-raspbian and just figured out that there's no /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf for me.

I can successfully record sound by specifying USB mic but not sure how to make it default for the system without editing alsa-base.conf.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, first delete the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` Raspbian Jessie does not use this config file like Wheezy did.

Now, to set the USB sound card to your default card you will need to edit the file `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` with the command `sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` scroll down until you find the lines

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

and change them to

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

Explanation: USB sound cards are registered as card 1 on Raspbian Jessie. On Wheezy they would be registered as card -2 by default and editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` would change that.

I do not know if this next step is necessary but without it my card wouldn't work.

Create and edit the file `~/.asoundrc` by using the command `sudo nano`~/.asoundrc` and change it so that it only reads this:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Now your default audio out (speakers) and audio in (mic) are your usb device.

Comment: can you do this seperately for audio out and in? Id like to keep hdmi as audio out, but just use an usb sound card to have a audio in as well.

Comment: Hi Leo, did you solve this?

Comment: I also would need help for using usb micro as default input and keep another card as default output.

Comment: Did anyone manage to keep input and output separate? Like many other people I would like to have HDMI as audio out and usb audio in.

Comment: I would also like to use HDMI output and USB mic input.