# setting up a USB mic on RPi

Tags: raspbian

I am currently working on creating a "magic mirror", from those unfamiliar the project can be found at https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/magic-mirror/ . Thought I am having trouble with my Raspberry Pi when it comes to a usb microphone I purchased. The exact product I bought ([http://www.amazon.com/Super-Microphone-Adapter-Driver-Notebook/product-reviews/B00M3UJ42A/ref=cm_cr_pr_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=recent&pageNumber=2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M3UJ42A)) despite what I read online is not just plug in and go.

So my question is how do I set up this microphone.. I am very new to RPi and linux so be easy on me. But I have all the code set up of voice commands, but when I plug in an speak into the mic nothing happens leading me to believe there has to be some set up involved. If anyone could please explain to me what needs to be done or point me in the direction of a tutorial that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

To clarify.. all I want to do is have the mic hear what I am saying, I do not want any output.

FYI I am running a RPi 2 model B

Comment: Can you give us some more info on what steps you took, software-wise, to set up the mic?

Comment: as of right now the only things I have done is follow in the instructions on from the link in the amazon product description

Comment: Are you running Raspbian Jessie or Wheezy

Comment: For Raspbian Jessie: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39879/33979

Comment: For Raspbian Wheezy: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/21989/33979

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the possibel duplicates (please check the links provided by Patrick) don't fully address your question please edit it to include why. Thanks! And please be so kind to provide input which raspbian you're running.