# Configuring Raspberry Pi 2 to use USB Microphone and Headset as default device on Jessie

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I am attempting to setup a Plantronics .Audio 400 DSP with a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B as the default device with Jessie installed.
Headset Link: http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/audio-400-dsp

So far in all attempts I have been unsuccessful in setting this up as the default device.  The USB is recognized by the Pi, and manually selecting this via aplay or arecord work:

```
aplay test.wav –Dsysdefault:CARD=DSP
arecord test.wav –Dsysdefault:CARD=DSP
```

Below I will include some research I have done and what I attempted:

- [Unable to set default input and output audio device on Raspberry jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39928/unable-to-set-default-input-and-output-audio-device-on-raspberry-jessie)

  - On reboot of the device, it appears asoundrc is getting rewritten so
    that card 1 is now card 0.
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=129514

  - This removes the default sound/microphone from the devices.  However, when trying to test this with aplay or arecord, I am getting a ‘Channels count not available’.
  - This does however allow me to listen to sound via a browser
- [How to reorder the index for mic on new Raspbian Jessie for PocketSphinx?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38161/how-to-reorder-the-index-for-mic-on-new-raspbian-jessie-for-pocketsphinx)

  - Did not adjust anything
- [How do I configure my sound for Jasper on Raspbian Jessie?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/how-do-i-configure-my-sound-for-jasper-on-raspbian-jessie)

  - The indexing did not work for me, but I would love to see if Housni creates a bash script

In short, does anyone have detailed instructions on how to connect a USB Headset (microphone + headphones) to a Raspberry Pi 2 with Jessie installed as the default device?

Thanks!

Comment: Been trying to do the same thing with the same headphones. The program PulseAudio Volume Control helps to set various options for input and output of sound devices. But I have yet to get the microphone to work on the headset. Sorry this isn't too helpful.

Comment: Try this? http://superuser.com/a/1045885/20881

Answer (score 1):

Have you been trying to create and use an ~/.asoundrc file?
I have not been using USB-speakers or microphones yet but set my Bluetooth speakers and microphones as system-defaults via this file.

Create the file ~/.asoundrc with the following content:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

> Explanation: USB sound cards are registered as card 1 on Raspbian Jessie. (see: [Best way to setup USB mic as system default on Raspbian Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/best-way-to-setup-usb-mic-as-system-default-on-raspbian-jessie))

If this does not help I provide you my working bluetooth-config, maybe you are able to translate it according to your USB-device-properties:

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave {
                pcm {
                        type bluealsa
                        device <MAC>
                        profile "a2dp"
                }
        }
        hint {
                show on
                description "Calisto"
        }
}
ctl.!default {
        type bluealsa
}
```

EDIT: It seems that you also have to edit your alsa-base.conf file. Have look at: [Unable to set default input and output audio device on Raspberry jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39928/unable-to-set-default-input-and-output-audio-device-on-raspberry-jessie?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

From your first link, change your default cards to 1, and also delete the hashtag on the line that says, `load card-specific configuration files (on request)`. Then go into and edit `/lib/modprobe.d/aliases.conf` and change the line, `options snd-usb-audio index=-2`, to, `options snd-usb-audio index=0`, then run, `cat /proc/asound/cards`, and check to see that your device is at 0.

References:
- https://superuser.com/questions/989385/alsa-base-conf-missing-in-new-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jesse
- http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/raspberrypi